# Where do I place the applicationContext.xml file within Spring project directory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn about the Spring framework for Java and I am not sure where about's I am supposed to put the applicationContext.xml file for configuring the spring beans. My directory structure is as follows:

[image: Spring directory layout]

Do I put in .settings?  Or should it be put at the top level within springapp?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put into directory `WebContent/WEB-INF`.

**Resources placed into `WEB-INF` folder are not accessible from web, they are application internal resources.** This is good, because your `applicationContext.xml` shouldn't be accessible from web.

Other good options are `WebContent/WEB-INF/classes` or just `src` (both are equal).

Files and folders with `.` contains Eclipse configuration files, they are internal for Eclipse - do not use them.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice and the help.Some good answers from everyone here but I think this one is the most useful.

Comment: using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` it didnt worked, i've to put it all the xml into `org.example.hello/references/some.xml`

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to put it in the `src` (or `src/META-INF`) folder and access it via `classpath:applicationContext.xml` (or `classpath:META-INF/applicationContext.xml`). (Eclipse will copy this file to WebContent/WEB-INF/classes when it build the war archive.)

Because:

- The mayor advantage of `src` over `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` / `WebContent-WEB-INF` is, that you can access the `src` files even in the tests (via `classpath:applicationContext.xml`)
- Do NOT put it `.settings` because the content of this directory gets not deployed in the Web App (it is eclipse configuration folder)

*Of course when you use maven, then put the file in `src\main\resources` (or `src\main\resources\META-INF`), Maven will copy them to the classpath folder while compiling.*

Answer (score 1):

`WEB-INF` or its subdirectories. This folder's content is packed directly into the root `war` file, so files that are directly under this folder are accessible as resources with path like `'/foo.xml'` (or in spring notation `classpath:/foo.xml`

Comment: Shouldn't it be in `/WEB-INF/classes` for that to be true? In eclipse, it would be under a source folder.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be in the classpath.  You can put the original editable instance anywhere (e.g. a `config` directory off the root) but then you will need to have your build management tool (e.g. `Ant` or `Maven`) copy it into the classpath for the runtime.